# What's the point of custom fields on external objects?

Tags: custom-field, lightning-connect

If they are not mapped to the schema what's the point of creating custom fields on external objects? I have tested with a checkbox field and verified that my changes are not being preserved, as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer [Define External Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_object_define.htm&type=0) documentation, where it specifies the need of creating custom fields.

> If the external system allows it, we recommend that you *sync* the external data source to automatically create related external objects. *You can instead choose to manually define external objects to customize the external object names and manually create the custom fields*.

Also, think about creation of indirect lookup. Refer: [Large Data Volume - Design your data model](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/large-data-volumes/units/design-your-data-model) trailhead.

> When you create an indirect lookup relationship field on an external object, you specify the parent object field and the child object field to match against each other, selecting a *custom unique external ID field* on the parent object to match against the child’s indirect lookup relationship field, whose values are determined by the specified External Column Name.

Comment: I see; it provides an alternative to syncing.